# Query with GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

I have little problem with mysql query. I need something like GROUP_CONCAT in GROUP_CONCAT. LOOK:

Database design :

[image]

```
SELECT cid, country, capital,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT mid, '=',city SEPARATOR '|*|') AS data
FROM t1
    INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.c_id = t1.cid
    INNER JOIN t3 ON t2.c_id = t3.mid
WHERE t1.cid =1
```

Return

```
[cid] => 1
[country] => France
[capital] => Paris
[data] => 1=Lyon|*|2=Chartres|*|3=Valence
```

But I want join to this query table t4 (I haven't idea how to do this) and it will be good if output will be looks like this

```
[cid] => 1
[country] => France
[capital] => Paris
[data] => 1=Lyon=|*|2=Chartres=Max#Alex#Frank|*|3=Valence=John
```

ps. 
t4.m_id = t3.mid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure why you would want to do this in SQL, but here is a version that returns the desired result:

```
SELECT  t1.cid,
  t1.country,
  t1.capital,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t34.mid,"=", t34.city, "=", t34.names ORDER BY t34.mid SEPARATOR "|*|" )AS data
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 
  ON t1.cid = t2.c_id
LEFT JOIN
(
  select t3.mid, t3.city,
    Coalesce(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t4.names SEPARATOR "#"), '') names
  from table3 t3
  left join table4 t4
    on t3.mid= t4.m_id
  group by t3.mid, t3.city
) t34
  ON t2.city_id = t34.mid
where t1.cid = 1
group by t1.cid, t1.country
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/869b9/23)

Result:

```
| CID | COUNTRY | CAPITAL |                                                DATA |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1 |  France |   Paris | 1=Lyon=|*|2=Chartes=Max#Alex#Frank|*|3=Valence=John |
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data model is very confusing... I mean `t2.city_id = t3s.mid`... seriously?

Anyway, here's a solution:

```
SELECT cid, country, capital, GROUP_CONCAT(city_list SEPARATOR "|*|") AS data
FROM (
  SELECT mid, CONCAT(mid, "=", city, "=", COALESCE(names_list, "")) AS city_list
  FROM (
    SELECT m_id, GROUP_CONCAT(names SEPARATOR '#') AS names_list
    FROM t4
    GROUP BY m_id
  ) AS t4s
  RIGHT JOIN t3 ON t3.mid = t4s.m_id
) AS t3s
JOIN t2 ON t2.city_id = t3s.mid
JOIN t1 ON t1.cid = t2.c_id
GROUP BY cid
```

Result:

```
| CID | COUNTRY | CAPITAL |                                                 DATA |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1 |  France |   Paris | 1=Lyon=|*|2=Chartres=Max#Alex#Frank|*|3=Valence=John |
```

[View on SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48236/1)

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6d65/53/0) for testing.

```
select distinct cid,country,capital,
group_concat(distinct t3.mid,"=",city, '=', coalesce(names, '') separator "|*|") as data
from t1
inner join t2 on t2.c_id = t1.cid
inner join t3 on t2.city_id = t3.mid
left join (select m_id, group_concat(names separator '#') as names
           from t4
           group by m_id) t5 on t3.mid = t5.m_id
where t1.cid =1;
```